# cluster many curves representing gas consumption

Tags: r

I have 700 hourly time series from 2010 to 2014 of gas consumption. One time serie represents the consumption of one companies. 
Some have constant consumption, other consume only 4 months of the year and some have a high volatility consumption. As a consequence I would like to cluster them according to the shape of the consuption curve.

I tried the R package "kml", but i do not have good results. I also tried the "kmlShape" package, but it seems that i have too much data, and each time R quit..

I wondered if using Fast fourier transform and then cluster it could be a good idea? My goal is  to really distinguish the group that the consumption is constant to those whose consumption is variable.
Then I would like to cluster the variable consummer in function of the peak and when they consumme.

I also tried to calculate the mean et variance of each clients, then cluster it with k-mean but it not very good, i can see 2 cluster, one with 650 clients and on other with 50...

thanks

Comment: Please add example data, and clarify what the desired output should look like exactly. "Cluster them" is not sufficient information.

Comment: Fourier transformation is a normal way for such purposes. Also, you can try to "decompose" your data with some wavelet analysis technics. Look at `dwt` function in `wavelets` package.

Answer (score 0):

[first exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol2Au.png)`
[2nd exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9CAM.png)

Here are three exemple of what I have, I have 700 curves likes that, some are high variables, some pretty constant.

I would like to cluster them according to their shape in order to have one group where the consumption is pretty constant, an other where the consumption is highly variable and try to cluster it according to the time the peak appear

Comment: Is this a solution or just more information for your question? If it is not a solution, please move this information to your question and delete this answer. (You will get many many fewer views if it has an answer, valid or not.)